# Using reader as POST body with Spring declarative REST client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I want to use Spring declarative REST client to POST a Reader as body, in this way:

```
@HttpExchange
public interface MyRestClient {

    @PostExchange(value = "/postString")
    public int postTextFile(@RequestBody Reader body);
}
```

but I receive this error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported for bodyType=java.io.InputStreamReader
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.writeWithMessageWriters(BodyInserters.java:430)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.lambda$fromValue$1(BodyInserters.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientRequestBuilder$BodyInserterRequest.writeTo(DefaultClientRequestBuilder.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$exchange$1(ExchangeFunctions.java:102)
    at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.lambda$connect$2(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:147)
```

How can I solve the problem?
And it is possibile to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the right solution, because, honestly, it seems to me too complex.

But at the moment here it is what I did to solve the problem.

I implemented a new `HttpMessageWriter` for the `Reader` type:

```
public class ReaderMessageWriter implements HttpMessageWriter<Reader> {

    private static final MediaType TEXT_PLAIN_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    private final List<MediaType> mediaTypes;

    public ReaderMessageWriter() {
        this.mediaTypes = MediaType.asMediaTypes(List.of(
                MimeTypeUtils.TEXT_PLAIN,
                MimeTypeUtils.ALL
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getWritableMediaTypes() {
        return mediaTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(ResolvableType elementType, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (mediaType == null) {
            return true;
        }
        for (MimeType candidate : this.mediaTypes) {
            if (candidate.isCompatibleWith(mediaType)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> write(
            Publisher<? extends Reader> inputStream,
            ResolvableType elementType,
            MediaType mediaType,
            ReactiveHttpOutputMessage message,
            Map<String, Object> hints) {

        return Mono.from(inputStream)
                .flatMap(reader -> {

                    final HttpHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
                    headers.setContentType(TEXT_PLAIN_UTF8);
                    headers.set(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked");

                    Flux<DataBuffer> body = DataBufferUtils.readInputStream(
                            () -> ReaderInputStream.builder()
                                    .setReader(reader)
                                    .setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                                    .get(),
                            message.bufferFactory(),
                            Streams.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

                    return message.writeWith(body);
                });
    }
}
```

And I registered it into a `WebClient` in this way:

```
    return WebClient.builder()
            .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer
                    .customCodecs()
                    .register(new ReaderMessageWriter()))
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
            .build();
```

Now I can create declarative REST interface like this:

```
@PostExchange(value = "/postString", contentType = "text/plain")
public int postStringWithReader(@RequestBody Reader body);
```

and use it.

I waiting for feedback. Because I repeat, it seems too complex to me, and I'm still not sure about the solution I found.